# Insert CATextLayer inside UIBezierPath and rotate

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, catextlayer

In the following example I'm trying to insert a `CATextLayer` inside a `UIBezierPath` and rotate it -45 degrees.

```
class DiagonalView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY + (rect.midY / 2.5)))
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.midX + (rect.midX / 2.5), y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.midX - (rect.midX / 10.5), y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY - (rect.midY / 10.5)))

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        let textlayer = CATextLayer.init()
        textlayer.string = "iPhone X"
        textlayer.fontSize = 12
        textlayer.isWrapped = true
        textlayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        textlayer.frame = path.bounds
        let degrees = -45.0
        let radians = CGFloat(degrees * Double.pi / 180)
        textlayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10, 50, 0)
        textlayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0)
        layer.addSublayer(textlayer)
    }

}


let containerView = DiagonalView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 140.0, height: 140.0))
containerView.backgroundColor = .red
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
```

Although its not actually the result that I expected

Result
[image]

Expected
[image]

Any idea of what mistake I might have done with the code?
Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: None of your layers have sizes or positions (frames). So they are going to behave very oddly. You need to get control of where each layer is, how big it is, and (in the case of your text) what point it rotates around.

Comment: @matt so what do you suggest doing here? Sorry but I'm newb with the layers in a UIView!